# Byte-range support in gin-gonic

Tags: go, go-gin

Im trying to get byte-range support working in the gin-gonic framework for Golang, or it's just basically fetching media in chunks/streaming.

I've been around googling a whole lot, and found some things that don't really fit my case.
I've been trying to use

```
c.File(filePath)
```

I don't have a filePath only a reader because I interact with google cloud storage.

I have also tried with

```
c.DataFromReader(200, rc.Size(), "audio/mpeg", rc, extraHeaders)
```

but im not sure that it's what I was really looking for and does not work anyway.

How does one do this in the gin-gonic framework?

Comment: Can you issue a byte range request to the data source? If so, forward the byte range headers to gcloud and the byte response headers back to the client.  Also consider having the cient read directly from the datasource.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's possible actually. How do I define a byte range request in gin-gonic? Is it just a normal GET or is there more to it?

Comment: Use the net/http package to make the request and set the headers as needed. You should be able to copy the relevant server request headers to the client request.

Comment: I tried to implement it in gin and didn't get it working. Do you have any example for using gin?